# Post request in Emberjs with Django rest

Tags: ember.js, django-rest-framework

I am trying to do some crud applications 
My Backend is Django Rest Framework front end i'm using Emberjs

I am not able to perform  post request i'm getting unsupported media error here is my code

```js
//model js customer.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  company: DS.attr('string'),
  title: DS.attr('string')
});


//route customer.js

import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model(params){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      customers: this.store.findAll('customers'),
    })
  },
  actions:{
    saveCustomer(){
      let customer = this.store.CreateRecord('customers',{
        name: this.getProperties('name'),
        company: this.getProperties('company'),
        city: this.getProperties('cist'),
      })
      customer.save();
    }
  },
});


//template customers.hbs

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>City</th>
  </tr>
  {{#each customers as |customer|}}
     <tr>
       <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
       <td>{{customer.company}}</td>
       <td>{{customer.city}}</td>
     </tr>
   {{/each}}
</table>
{{#paper-form onSubmit=(route-action "saveCustomer") as |form|}}
  <div class="layout-row">
    <div class="layout-column flex-50">
      {{form.input label="Full Name" value=name onChange=(action (mut name)) required=true}}
      {{form.input label="company" value=company onChange=(action (mut company))}}
      {{form.input label="city" value=city onChange=(action (mut city))}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="layout-row">
    {{#form.submit-button raised=true primary=true}}Submit{{/form.submit-button}}
  </div>
{{/paper-form}}


// adapter application.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1',
  host: 'http://localhost:8000'
});
```

any one who can help to get out of this ..I am using my backed django rest framework.I tried my backed code in post man it works well but when i'm using with ember i'm not able to post request form client side

Comment: What media type did you use in your postman requests? The same ember-data uses (`application/json`)? If your back-end is returning an error, maybe you should be looking at your back-end...

Comment: iam getting this error   POST http://localhost:8000/api/v1/customers 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Answer (score 2):

My [understanding](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/models/customizing-serializers/) is that emberjs works with jsonapi.org request/response format. Take a look at [DJA (Django REST Framework JSON API)](http://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which adds on to Django REST Framework.

There are a few active [PRs](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api/pulls) and [enhancement issues](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api/issues) with DJA to implement some of the more advanced JSON API features in case you are missing something....

Comment: JSONAPI is the default ember comes with. You can use any request/response format given you have customized the serializers for it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your backend accepts content-type `application/vnd.api+json`, you need to set the header.

Answer (score 1):

I've use this exact stack and know exactly what your problem is (I think).

It's not an ember issue at all (I believe). I believe you may have misconfigured your Django-Rest-Framework settings.

In your settings.py (or however you've configured things) your `REST_FRAMEWORK` dict should have these entries:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
     )
}
```

I'd also **strongly** recommend using JSON:API to format your API. https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api